# How to solve hibernate auto create issue on PostgreSQL with array field?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

One of my entity includes an array field, I mapped using hibernate-types-52 library:

```
@TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class)
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEntity implements Synchronizable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "some_table_id", sequenceName = "some_table_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_table_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "values")
    @Type(type = "string-array")
    private String[] values;
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: my.package.PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect
```

PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

public class PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect
        extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "array");
        this.registerColumnType(Types.OTHER, "jsonb");
    }
}
```

Issue:

```
o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : 
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : 
Error executing DDL "create table some_table (id int8 not null, values array)" via JDBC Statement ...
```

So, SQL part "values array" looks very weird. How should I change hibernate options or my code to fix it?

Comment: You need to specify the column definition for proper DDL. Look at the Hibernate-Types examples in the repository

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling, thank you, it works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to specify the `columnDefinition` for proper table DDL, like so:

```java
@TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class)
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEntity implements Synchronizable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "some_table_id", sequenceName = "some_table_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_table_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "values")
    @Type(type = "string-array", columnDefinition = "text[]")
    private String[] values;
}
```